# Deserialize of a json string give error outside bounds of array

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to Serialize this string:

```
{data:[{key:"0",value:"local"},{key:"0",value:"xmlstring"},{key:"1",value:"json"}],type:[{key:"1",def:"1",description:"",constructor:"",function:"",script:"",standard:"",value:"{val}",builder:"{3}"}]}
```

with this:

```
var jsonStandardPropObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObj>(_DefaultObjProps);
```

However it give error:

Index was outside the bounds of the array.

It worked good before, however I removed the double qoutes from the objects and numeric values.
Is there anyway to get this working so I can seriale this string like this?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.  JSON properties _must_ be double-quoted.

Comment: Why are you manually building JSON strings in the first place??

Comment: I have no problems when reading the JSON string from a file and calling the code from the sample.

Comment: If you like to check if json is valid, use http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I know it works with the double quotes, but I have other strings like this which are without the double quotes and they are being read in corretly. I just wonder why this is not possible....

Comment: Same thing is happening to me, don't have a clue where it is coming from!